# tar - List of extracted files

Tags: tar, archive

How can I extract files from a *.tar.gz* archive while keeping a trace of the extracted files?

For example, let's say I have the following file structure...

```
ROOT
 ╠═▶ children
 ║    ╠═▶ joe.txt
 ║    ╚═▶ george.txt
 ╠═▶ bar.txt
 ╠═▶ foo.txt
 ╚═▶ A̲R̲C̲H̲I̲V̲E̲.t̲a̲r̲.b̲z̲
      ├─▷ children
      │    ├─▷ joe.txt
      │    └─▷ bob.txt
      ├─▷ hello.txt
      ├─▷ world.txt
      └─▷ foo.txt
```

Now, if I extract the files from the archive while keeping the newer files in place I'd like to know which ones have been extracted so I can do something like this:
`tar xf ./ARCHIVE.tar.gz --keep-newer-files | xargs -I EXTRACTED_FILE echo EXTRACTED_FILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the option `--to-command` to trigger the print of all extracted files

the argument is a command that will use the env variable TAR_FILENAME to have the file name , and will receive thee file on `STDIN`

So you must read `STDIN`  and create the extracted file ,  you can print on `STDOUT` the file you created

```
tar -xzf ../ARCH.tgz --keep-newer-files \
   --to-command="sh -c $(printf '%q' \
  'mkdir -p "$(dirname "$TAR_FILENAME")";dd of="$TAR_FILENAME" >/dev/null 2>&1;echo "#EXTRACTED#$TAR_FILENAME" ')" > output_tar.txt
```

and in `output_tar.txt` you will have a line for each extracted file .

See [Writing to an External Program](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html) for more details

Comment: I tried it and I thought it worked for a second but I realized output_tar.txt contains the list of files that would be extracted has expected but nothing is extracted from the archive.It does not extract the files.

Comment: This why in my example , the command has 2 parts . one part for a dd command , and one part to echo the filename

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm dumb but I don't understand.
I tried to redirect stderr of `dd` into a file and it says `dd: failed to open 'file/in/archive.txt': No such file or directory` for every file that should be extracted

Comment: I managed to fix this issue by making sure the file pre-existed before calling `dd`. Here is the command I used for the `--to-command` argument of tar:
`sh -c $(printf '%q' 'mkdir -p $(dirname $TAR_FILENAME) ; touch $TAR_FILENAME ; dd of="$TAR_FILENAME" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo "#EXTRACTED#$TAR_FILENAME" ')`

Answer (score 0):

Depending of my requirement,
I sometimes need to list all available extracted files
matching the archive content (whether or not newer).

In that case, I can list the files effectively extracted,
once the tar extraction was performed (or not).

I do it like this:

```
tar -xzf ./ARCH.tgz --keep-newer-files
for file in $(tar -tf ./ARCH.tgz 2>/dev/null)
do
  if [[ -e $file && ! -d $file ]]
  then
    echo $file
  fi
done > output_tar.txt
```

A maybe less explicit but concise solution using xargs is:

```
tar -tf ./ARCH.tar 2>/dev/null | xargs -L1 bash -c 'if [[ -e $0 && ! -d $0 ]]; then echo $0; fi;'
```